# Google map url is not working in android app

Tags: android, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am sending a url for google map as a push notification from my node js application. 
My example url is like below
http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:28.501947+77.071472

When I try to open this url in browser it is working fine.

But when I try to open this through android google map application it shows to some default location irrespective of the latitude and longitude value.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to snatch the latitude and longitude from the url and set the map with this lat long
*loc:28.501947+77.071472*

- lat = 28.501947
- long = 77.071472

Comment: If I get this url as sms and want to open in google map. then also the same problem is coming..